# Sitecore - How to remove a Profile Card assigned to an Item?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

How do I remove a (customized) profile card assigned to a Sitecore Item?

[image: Evidence]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way, just to delete it:

1. You should click on profile and set all its values to 0

Complex way, to understand how it is saved:

1. Enable "Raw values" and "Standard fields" checkboxes on "View" tab
2. Find "Advanced" section "Tracking" field
3. This field is XML where you are able to remove required
   "profile"node